# JPA just delete in the second click

Tags: java, jpa

My JPA is deleting the first result(when refresh browser) just in the second click, for example i open the listing page now, and in the last column there is a command link to delete:

```
<h:form>
<p:dataTable blah blah blah>

other columns...
    <p:column>
    <p:commandLink action="#{automovelBean.excluir(auto)}" value="Deletar" update=""></p:commandLink>
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

now my bean to delete:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();

        automovel = em.getReference(Automovel.class, automovel.getId());
        em.remove(automovel);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
```

if i click in the "excluir"(delete), nothing happens in the datable, if i click in the second row it update the datable and show that the first record was deleted and the second too, no problem in this, the problem is:

if someone click in the delete of the first item and see that the datable is not updating and not removing the result in the listing, people will probably click again in the same delete button and so it will delete the second result too, but the user do not see this and if you click a lot of times it will delete all the results =(

my first try was to add the update="dataTableId" in the commandLink, but it is not working =/

sorry bad english

Answer (score 0):

Solved

Changes:

1) Added a ID to the dataTable, just add id="idname"

2) all the dataTable inside a `<h:form>`

3) Command link just added the update="idname" of the dataTable, and now its refreshing in "real time"

Comment: don't forget to accept your own answer, so you can close this question